# Problem on Probability based on co-ordinate points

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let S be the array of integral points (x, y, z) with x=0,1,2 ; y=0,1,2,3 ; z=0,1,2,3,4. What is the probability that if two points are chosen from S, their midpoint is in S?

Part where I am stuck:
Now for filling x we 3 choices for y we have 4 and z we have 5 so total points that are part of A are 3*4*5= 60
Selecting 2 of 60 is 60C2=1770 possible numbers can be selected from S. 
Now I am stuck on the part where we have to find number of pairs of such points whose midpoint is in S itself. I cannot think of a way to do so.

Comment: The answer given is 52/177

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE, you are more likely to get a response if you show what you have tried. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Stuart Stevenson thanks for the suggestion. I have added the details to the question.

Comment: Good man. I'm a programmer so I would probably write a script to count them all. If you have Matlab or something like that then that would be the way to go. If not, then you're going to have to sit down and find a way to get them systematically although this seems tedious. Programming is probably the way to go. If you need help with this then let me know.

Comment: Thanks I would definitely inform you of I need any help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I get a smaller answer (or two)

- There are $60^2=3600$ ways of choosing two points, in order and allowing duplication.  This reduces to $3540$ if you exclude the $60$ duplicates (and would then reduce to your $1770$ by ignoring order)
- For a midpoint to be a point on the array, the parities of the co-ordinates of the two picked points must be the same in each dimension so that their averages are integers

  - In the $x$ co-ordinate there are $2^2+1^2 = 5$ ways of matching the parities
  - In the $y$ co-ordinate there are $2^2+2^2 = 8$ ways of matching the parities
  - In the $z$ co-ordinate there are $3^2+2^2 = 13$ ways of matching the parities
- So overall there are $5 \times 8 \times 13 = 520$ ways of matching the parities.   If you ignore the $60$ overall duplicates this reduces to $460$

So the probability looks to me like $\frac{520}{3600} =\frac{13}{90}$ if you allow duplicate picks, or $\frac{460}{3540} =\frac{23}{177}$ if you exclude duplicate picks

Comment: I get the same with a script.

Comment: I followed the same logic matching parities but I was not getting 520 ways. Could you please explain how you get 2²+1²=5 ways and others. I guess that would satisfy my doubt.

Comment: Please could you explain what I have asked in above comment Henry.

Comment: @DhruvDeshmukh To get $2^2+1^2$ matching parities, either the first $x$ co-ordinate is $0$ or $2$ and the second $x$ co-ordinate is $0$ or $2$ (so $2^2$ ways), or the first $x$ co-ordinate is $1$ and the second $x$ co-ordinate is $1$ (so $1^2$ way).  Similarly with the $y$ and $z$ co-ordinates

Comment: Okay I get it now. And just a small question. In your answer you use the word duplicate. Does it mean taking the same point twice(i.e. considering a point say (0,0,0) twice.)? Thanks Henry for the help.

Comment: @DhruvDeshmukh Taking $(0,0,0)$ twice is one of the $60$ duplicates.  Taking $(2,1,1)$ twice is another, and so on

Comment: Okay thanks. I think your answer is correct and the one in my workbook may be wrong.Because in answer 520/1770, 1770 does not consider order and duplicates but 520 considers order and duplicates which seems contradictory.